# search for 2 occurrences in relational table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I have a table filled with categories, another filled with products.
Between them, I have a products-categories table with only 3 columns :

- id
- category_id
- product_id

works fine to look up products in a certain category :

```
LEFT JOIN `products-categories` pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
```

(p being my products table.)

When looking for products in certain categories, I simply use :

```
WHERE pc.category_id IN (0,34,35,36,37,38,39,168)
```

but now how can I combine 2 categories clauses?
I would like to find all products present in, lets say categories 34 AND 255

I can't just add a ' AND WHERE' because this relation will be on a different line (There is only one category_id for each resulting lines...

### Example:

```
product_id | category_id
1            22
1            34
1            47
2            34
2            65
2            255
2            313
3            22
```

My product Table simply looks 'somehow' like that :

```
id | name | price | ...
-----------------
1    fork   2.21
2    knife  3.55
```

So what I try to do in plain english is :

Find all products in category 34 that **also** appear in category 255
this should return me the product ID 2 (only once)

Doing it this way **is wrong** : 
(This is real code)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ref`,`spec_varc_titre_fr`,`price_sell`,`spec_bool_new`,`defaultmedia_id` 
FROM `productmanager_products` p 
LEFT JOIN `productmanager_products-categories` pc 
ON p.id = pc.product_id 
WHERE pc.category_id IN (0,34,35,36,37,38,39,168)
AND spec_varc_gender = 'F' 
AND pc.category_id IN (0,255) 
AND `price_sell` BETWEEN 1.27 
AND 38.83 
ORDER BY pc.ordering ASC 
LIMIT 0,15;
```

because 34 and 255 are on different rows even if they are the same product...

Comment: so what if the products belongs to 34 AND 255 as well some other val does that kind of product should also be counted ?

Comment: yes. as long as there are at least for product_id #1, 2 lines : 1-34 and 1-255

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty just added example to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way in MySQL is to use `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select pc.productId
from product_categories pc
where categoryId in (34, 255)
group by pc.productId
having count(*) = 2;
```

EDIT:

If you want to check for equivalence classes, you can use a similar idea in a more general form:

```
select pc.productId
from product_categories pc
group by pc.productId
having sum(CategoryId in (34, 35, 36)) > 0 and
       sum(CategoryId in (254, 255, 256)) > 0;
```

Comment: but I have 2 lists of categoryIDs, lets say : 34,35,36 and 254,255,256 line should return if 'present' in both these lists

Comment: What do you mean "in both these lists"?  That would mean they have ids 34, 35, 36, 254, 255, and 256 -- the same idea as in this answer.

Comment: Just added a real example in my original question to make it a bit clearer

Comment: @VincentDuprez . . . The first answer should have products in both categories 34 and 255 (my last edit just changed the category numbers).

Comment: I'm getting weird results and query times up to 10 seconds... (from 30ms before)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a inner join between **2 select statements.** this seams to be the way to go to get the common, the same rows.

theoretical code :

```
select * from
  (select * from table) A
inner join
  (select * from table2) B
on A.id = B.id
```

raw code for archive :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS A.`id`,A.`ref`,A.`spec_varc_titre_fr`,A.`price_sell`,A.`spec_bool_new`,A.`defaultmedia_id` FROM
                    ( 
                            SELECT DISTINCT `id`,`ref`,`spec_varc_titre_fr`,`price_sell`,`spec_bool_new`,`defaultmedia_id`
                            FROM `productmanager_products` p 
                            LEFT JOIN `productmanager_products-categories` pc 
                            ON p.id = pc.product_id 
                            WHERE pc.category_id IN (0,35) 

                            AND `price_sell` BETWEEN 1.83 
                            AND 20.45 
                            AND price_sell > 0
                            ORDER BY pc.ordering ASC 
                    ) A
                        inner join
                    (
                            SELECT DISTINCT `id`,`ref`,`spec_varc_titre_fr`,`price_sell`,`spec_bool_new`,`defaultmedia_id`
                            FROM `productmanager_products` p 
                            LEFT JOIN `productmanager_products-categories` pc 
                            ON p.id = pc.product_id 
                            WHERE pc.category_id IN (0,98) 

                            AND `price_sell` BETWEEN 1.83 
                            AND 20.45 
                            AND price_sell > 0
                            ORDER BY pc.ordering ASC 
                    ) B
                    ON A.`ref` = B.`ref`
                    LIMIT 0,15;
```